# Do not stop JavaScript when it throws an exception

Tags: javascript, exception, try-catch

I am writing a Windows Sidebar Gadget using JavaScript. Now I would like to have all JavaScript exceptions caught and logged to a text file. One problem is that when an exception is thrown at any line, the next line will not be executed. Is it possible to catch exceptions automatically so that the following line of JavaScript can be executed.

Here is the sample code which demonstrates my problem:

```
try
{
    alert(document.getElementById("non-existing-element").value);
}
catch(ex)
{
}
alert("This is shown.");
alert(document.getElementById("non-existing-element").value);
alert("This is not shown.");
```

So one big try-catch-method whould allow to log the error but the rest of the code would not be executed.
One solution would be to catch errors for every line. But would be too much code for several thousand lines. (or I write a macro which does this for me)
Maybe anyone can help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  I would seriously re-consider your approach.

Comment: Why not do proper error checking instead of catching exceptions, like [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jZP4M/)? It's worth pointing out that exceptions are supposed to be... you know... exceptional. They're **supposed** to cause the application to halt in the general use case.

Comment: The non-existing element was only an example. There could be any code that throws an exception in place of it.

Comment: Birk check out my answer about error suppression. It seems closer to what you may be looking for.

Comment: **see also:** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24318654

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of trying to catch errors, you should be trying to build proper logic to control them.

```
var myEle = document.getElementById("non-existing-element")

if (myEle != null)
   alert(dmyEle.value);
```

But you are describing suppressing errors

You **can** suppress error in JavaScript with a onerror event handler.

```
function handleErr(msg, url, line_no){ 
   var errorMsg = "Error: " + msg + "\n"; 
       errorMsg += "URL: " + url + "\n"; 
       errorMsg += "Line: " + line_no + "\n\n"; 

    alert(errorMsg); 

 return true;
} 

// Set the global onerror; 
onerror = handleErr;
```

More information [here](http://www.satya-weblog.com/2007/03/javascript-error-handling.html)

Answer (score 3):

No.  Exceptions always propagate up to the closest containing `try` block and then out of the `try` block if it has no `catch` and the `finally` exits normally.

There are no resumable exceptions in JavaScript, so no way to declare a single global exception handler and resume all exceptions.

Comment: This is not true, you can suppress errors, and handle them in your own defined handlers.

Comment: @Utilitron, If you're talking about `onerror` as in your answer, it does not allow you to resume execution at the point the error was raised so does not address the OP.  There is no code you can put in an `onerror` handler or the catch block below that will cause the alert to be executed in `try { throw new Error(); alert("Reached"); } catch { ... }`

Answer (score 2):

No easy solution but if you use something like jQuery and you do

```
$("#non-existing-element").attr('value')
```

would be better because attr is implemented to return nothing when there are no items found. I believe there is a name for this philosophy but I can't think of it.

Comment: The name of this philosophy is *Make sure your element exists before using it*.

Comment: @Frederic - I was actually thinking of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern Null Object Pattern

Answer (score 1):

Your proposed "ignore exceptions" method would only work if all your exceptions were unhandles *and* could be ignored. This is not the case in general since

1. Catching an exception is a form of flow control. You wouldn't want to mess up your for-loops, right?
2. The code following the exception line could very well depend on that line having executed correctly. (for example, someone could want to use that `.value`)

Therefore, the best you can hope to achieve is to see what kind of exceptions you are currently having and tune your debugging to it. Are you just having problems with elements not being found, as the initial example? Then add a test for null before using the node:

```
var node = document.getElementById('id');
if(!node) { /* inexisting element!*/ }
console.log('I dont have to worry about', node.value, 'now');
```

If your exceptions are coming from somewhere else then there is probably a similar solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to wrap each part within a try...catch trap.

Another alternative, use jQuery as it doesn't throw exceptions when elements are not found:

```
$('.non-existing-element').val();
```