# dinner cost calculator trouble converting string to integer

Tags: javascript, html, parseint

I'm using parseInt to convert .values from strings to numbers. However, if the user inputs a decimal value the output is NaN. Here is my code:

```
Dinner Cost:<input type="text" id="cost" /><br /><br />
Tax Rate:<input type="text" id="taxRate" /><br /><br />

<button id="btn">Determine Total Costs</button><br /><br />

<p id="para"></p>

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener('click', totalCosts);

function totalCosts() {

  var dinnerCosts = document.getElementById("cost").value;
  var taxRate = document.getElementById("taxRate").value;
  taxRate = parseInt(taxRate);
  dinnerCosts = parseInt(dinnerCosts);


  var taxCost = dinnerCosts * taxRate;
  var totalCost = dinnerCosts + taxCost;

  return document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = "Your dinner cost " + dinnerCosts + ", your tax costs " + taxCost + ", for a total cost of " + totalCost;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a more rational way to convert these default strings into numbers instead of parseInt?

Thanks!

Comment: use parseFloat() instead of parseInt() when expecting a floating point integer. It's preferred to use parseFloat() even if number is a proper integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use parseFloat() instead of parseInt() Usage: `taxRate = parseFloat(taxRate);`

As a better programming practice you should avoid exceptions in such conversions.One easy way to do robust type-checking in this Javascript scenario is to avoid:

- undeclared variables
- undeclared properties on Javascript objects (aka dictionary)
- Lnull values
- NaN values

Here is a simple and quick overview:

```
//
var vfftest       = 0.05;                       // float
var viitest       = 3000;                       // integer
var vssblank      = '';                         // empty string
var vssnonblank   = 'hello';                    // non-empty string
var vddempty      = {};                         // dictionary with no name-value pairs
var vddnonempty   = {'alpha':1,'bravo':'two'};  // dictionary with name-    value pairs
var vnull         = null;                       // null

// check parseFloat
console.log( parseFloat(vssnonblank) ); // NaN
console.log( parseFloat(vssblank) );    // NaN
console.log( parseFloat(vfftest) );     // 0.05
console.log( parseFloat(viitest) );     // 3000
console.log( parseFloat(vnull) );       // NaN
console.log( parseFloat(vddempty) );    // NaN
console.log( parseFloat(vddnonempty) ); // NaN
console.log( parseFloat(vnoExisto) );   // EXCEPTION
```

Other than that please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24318654/javascript-avoid-exceptions-for-string-to-integer-or-float-typecast-conversion) link and see how you avoid exceptions in such conversions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Number` constructor directly without instantiating it to return a literal number. Alternatively you could use `parseFloat`

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener('click', totalCosts);

function totalCosts() {

  var dinnerCosts = document.getElementById("cost").value;
  var taxRate = document.getElementById("taxRate").value;
  taxRate = Number(taxRate);
  dinnerCosts = Number(dinnerCosts);


  var taxCost = dinnerCosts * taxRate;
  var totalCost = dinnerCosts + taxCost;

  return document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = "Your dinner cost " + dinnerCosts + ", your tax costs " + taxCost + ", for a total cost of " + totalCost;
}
```

```html
Dinner Cost:<input type="text" id="cost" /><br /><br /> 
Tax Rate:<input type="text" id="taxRate" /><br /><br />

<button id="btn">Determine Total Costs</button><br /><br />

<p id="para"></p>
```